# Ordered JSON library due to SugarCRM bug

Tags: java, json, sugarcrm

This is horrible, but I need a library for java that maintains the order within JSON-objects. So is there any weirdly implemented JSON library out there that does this?

This is due to a bug in SugarCRM which makes it require certain order of each REST-call.

I've been told that they have fixed it for SugarCRM 7, but that wont be released until around mid next year(2014) and I need to do my implementation now.

http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html?caseID=34925#issue_34925

For example this does not work:

```
{"application_name":"lukasync","user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03535a5ae1b5aff4401a7283c4570d8b","version":"1"}}
```

But this does:

```
{"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03535a5ae1b5aff4401a7283c4570d8b","version":"1"},"application_name":"lukasync"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified the org.json one, only changing HashMap to LinkedHashMap in the JSONObject.
If anybody else stumbles over the same problem, here is the jar and when they fix it in SugarCRM you can just change back to the real org.json library.

https://github.com/spydon/NotJSON-java/blob/master/org.json.jar

Comment: To clarify, this is most likely only useful for SugarCRM 6.5 and earlier.